# SVN to Git mirror: git svn fetch -> Checksum mismatch

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I somehow managed to damage my previous `git svn` mirror that had worked quite flawless for many years now. But, I had to re-create the whole folder now, and I am stuck at this point.

So, since a previous `git svn clone` had failed due to the remote dropping connection, I headed into the folder, and tried to continue with `git svn fetch`. So far, so good. The revisions continued downloading, untill, I hit a very specific revision - and, this is th eonly one causing issues at the moment.

I want to resume maintenance of my mirror here: https://github.com/IngwiePhoenix/FLTK.git
From the official SVN repository stated at their website http://fltk.org

The error I am getting:

```
Checksum mismatch: branches/branch-1.1/fluid/icons/fluid.xcf.gz
expected: 68ce7be0b4a104b1c80a7c4dab0bad65
    got: aff1fbaf96ad04ae629fa0ea25d12595
```

I tried several "solutions" already:
- Tracking changes via `git svn log` and using `reset -rX -p` to roll back, and then fetching again.
- Actually, I deleted the whole thing and just outright tried to `git svn clone` all the way again (and although I have a very good downstream, the remote host does not seem to have the greatest upstream... so, downloading 4000 revisions takes *forever*).
- Using `git checkout` to head into `remotes/git-svn` and rebasing that.
- Using `git gc` and `git svn gc` in between all my steps - probably way more often, than I really had needed to.

No matter what I try, at this very commit, the whole bus just stops and crashes frontal. Oh, also: The given file is not being recognized. Running `git svn log $mismatchFile` tells me, that the given file was not recognized and that I should add two dashes (`--`). Doing so, and running the command again, only draws one line of dashes and that's it. Exit code is 0.

Any idea how I can fix that? I'd really like to re-start mirroring this project so I can use it as a Git submodule again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *just* svn (taking git out of the equation) gives me:

```
> svn co http://seriss.com/public/fltk/fltk/branches/branch-1.1/fluid/icons
A    icons/fluid-128.png
A    icons/fluid-16.png
A    icons/fluid-16i.png
A    icons/fluid-256.png
A    icons/fluid-32.png
A    icons/fluid-32.xpm
A    icons/fluid-32i.png
A    icons/fluid-48.png
A    icons/fluid-64.png
A    icons/fluid-96.xpm
A    icons/fluid.ico
svn: E200014: Checksum mismatch for '/tmp/icons/fluid.xcf.gz':
   expected:  68ce7be0b4a104b1c80a7c4dab0bad65
     actual:  aff1fbaf96ad04ae629fa0ea25d12595
```

So I guess their repo is broken. I think there is no chance that `git-svn` can handle something even `svn` refuses to handle.

Comment: As it turns out, as of december 1st, they actually shut their repo down and did their own Git repo. Darn... I should've stood in the mailing list :). Thank you for looking into this though!

Comment: You could just dump the repo: `svnadmin dump ...`, edit the dump by edit the broken commit or even remove it without revisions shift: https://superuser.com/questions/95432/want-to-delete-revisions-from-my-svn-repository/1742077#1742077 And commit removed changes again at the top revision.

Comment: `svnadmin` requires direct access to the repo storage location which the questioner does not have. And in case of corruption of that storage even svnadmin might fail.